# maven scm CVS plugin scm:diff

Tags: maven, maven-scm

I am trying to get the differences between revisions of the .sql files in the project as part of software release to execute the migration scripts. I am getting the empty out-put file when i execute the below command and i am not sure how to specify the files which are required to take the differences.

`mvn scm:diff -Dbasedir=D:\build-tool\util -DconnectionUrl="scm:cvs:pserver:192.168.1.3://utils:/utils" -Dusername=xxxxxx -Dincludes=*.sql -Dpassword=****** -DendScmVersion=1.1 -DendScmVersionType=revision  -DstartScmVersion=1.2 -DstartScmVersionType=revision  -Dmaven.scm.provider.cvs.implementation=cvs_native`

Can anyone please let me know where i misssed ?

Comment: Are the `sql` files at the top level directory of your repo?

Comment: No. they are in sql/*.sql, already tried like sql/*.sql still empty output file.